# Set global variables from another js file in vue 3

Tags: vue.js

Folder structure

```
main.js
/test/index.js
```

main.js file

```
import { createApp } from 'vue'
const app = createApp(App);
//the rest of code
app.config.globalProperties.$apple = "apple value";
app.config.globalProperties.$orange = "orangevalue";
```

/test/index.js file

```
app.config.globalProperties.$testvalue = "123";
```

How to set the global variable in `/test/index.js` in vue3

Answer (score 1):

In `/test/index.js` define a plugin with this content :

```js
export default {
  install: (app) => {
    app.config.globalProperties.$testvalue = "123";
  }
}
```

then in `main.js` use it in this way `app.use(testPlugin)`:

```js
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import testPlugin from './test'

const app = createApp(App);
//the rest of code
app.config.globalProperties.$apple = "apple value";
app.config.globalProperties.$orange = "orangevalue";
app.use(testPlugin)
```